# updating XML tag value in python

Tags: python, xml

In the below XML, I want to parse it and update the value only when it finds the `<Name>EveIapsGrdMes</Name>` then, in the next node, i.e. `<Value>12345</Value>`, only `Value` should be updated to `12345`. Could someone help me understand how to handle this?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<EDS>
    <Vector>
        <Number>1</Number>
        <ScalarSection>
            <Scalar>
                <Name>Patching_Path</Name>
                <Value>DO FlashManager.cmm "--patch --deviceName ALL"</Value>
                <Comment />
            </Scalar>
            <Scalar>
                <Name>EveIapsGrdMes</Name>
                <Value>A</Value>
                <Comment>EveIapsGrdMes Sensor Value</Comment>
            </Scalar>
            <Scalar>
                <Name>EveIapsOverTemp</Name>
                <Value>Icsp_Dem_Deb_LfEve_UNIONFIED.Icsp_Dem_Deb_LvErr_15[31]</Value>
                <Comment>EveIapsOverTemp Sensor Value</Comment>
            </Scalar>
            <Scalar>
                <Name>EveIapsUnderTemp</Name>
                <Value>Icsp_Dem_Deb_LfEve_UNIONFIED.Icsp_Dem_Deb_LvErr_15[32]</Value>
                <Comment>EveIapsUnderTemp Sensor Value</Comment>
            </Scalar>
            <EveDtsUnderTemp />
            <EveDtsOverTemp />
        </ScalarSection>
        <OneDMapSection />
        <TwoDMapSection />
    </Vector>
</EDS>
```

Here is my code. I can access until the Name tag `EveIapsGrdMes` but how to change the next `Value` tag?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 
with open('sys_bswm.xml', encoding="UTF-8") as f:
  tree = ET.parse(f)
  root = tree.getroot()
  for elem in root.getiterator():
      print(elem)
      try:
          if elem.tag=='Name':
              if elem.text == 'EveIapsGrdMes':
                  'Update the next tage Value, i,e <Value>12345</Value>'
              else:
                  'pass'

      except AttributeError:
          'pass' tree.write('sys_bswm.xml',xml_declaration=True,method='xml', encoding="UTF-8")
```

The first portion is completed. Need to do the second portion. Also, the result needs to write in the new XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below finds the required element and change the Value to a new value.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<EDS>
    <Vector>
        <Number>1</Number>
        <ScalarSection>
            <Scalar>
                <Name>Patching_Path</Name>
                <Value>DO FlashManager.cmm "--patch --deviceName ALL"</Value>
                <Comment />
            </Scalar>
            <Scalar>
                <Name>EveIapsGrdMes</Name>
                <Value>A</Value>
                <Comment>EveIapsGrdMes Sensor Value</Comment>
            </Scalar>
            <Scalar>
                <Name>EveIapsOverTemp</Name>
                <Value>Icsp_Dem_Deb_LfEve_UNIONFIED.Icsp_Dem_Deb_LvErr_15[31]</Value>
                <Comment>EveIapsOverTemp Sensor Value</Comment>
            </Scalar>
            <Scalar>
                <Name>EveIapsUnderTemp</Name>
                <Value>Icsp_Dem_Deb_LfEve_UNIONFIED.Icsp_Dem_Deb_LvErr_15[32]</Value>
                <Comment>EveIapsUnderTemp Sensor Value</Comment>
            </Scalar>
            <EveDtsUnderTemp />
            <EveDtsOverTemp />
        </ScalarSection>
        <OneDMapSection />
        <TwoDMapSection />
    </Vector>
</EDS>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
scalars = root.findall('.//Scalar')
for scalar in scalars:
  name = scalar.find('Name')
  print(name.text)
  if name.text == 'EveIapsGrdMes':
    value = scalar.find('Value')
    value.text = 'The new value you want to have'
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EDS>
   <Vector>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <ScalarSection>
         <Scalar>
            <Name>Patching_Path</Name>
            <Value>DO FlashManager.cmm "--patch --deviceName ALL"</Value>
            <Comment />
         </Scalar>
         <Scalar>
            <Name>EveIapsGrdMes</Name>
            <Value>The new value you want to have</Value>
            <Comment>EveIapsGrdMes Sensor Value</Comment>
         </Scalar>
         <Scalar>
            <Name>EveIapsOverTemp</Name>
            <Value>Icsp_Dem_Deb_LfEve_UNIONFIED.Icsp_Dem_Deb_LvErr_15[31]</Value>
            <Comment>EveIapsOverTemp Sensor Value</Comment>
         </Scalar>
         <Scalar>
            <Name>EveIapsUnderTemp</Name>
            <Value>Icsp_Dem_Deb_LfEve_UNIONFIED.Icsp_Dem_Deb_LvErr_15[32]</Value>
            <Comment>EveIapsUnderTemp Sensor Value</Comment>
         </Scalar>
         <EveDtsUnderTemp />
         <EveDtsOverTemp />
      </ScalarSection>
      <OneDMapSection />
      <TwoDMapSection />
   </Vector>
</EDS>
```

Comment: This is not part of the xml you have posted- right?

Comment: Yes it works, I have two header info and currently it is only writing one header i,e <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> How do I keep the other header information i,e <?altova_sps \\xyz\Templates\tmpl\eds.sps?>

Comment: Just use them in the input xml.